# Python unittest: Know which test in test suite queue

Tags: python, automated-tests, testng, python-unittest

Given an arbitrary number of tests in a test suite, is it possible for a test to know which test in the suite it is. I am in specific looking for a variable that I can use in test method to log some entries. The variable will identify which test the entry in the logs originated from. I am using unittest.

I tried to make something of my own but it will take a bit of time. Can not think of any work around other than hardcoding a string into each individual test in the suite (not scalable).

Comment: If you just want to print the test you are in, you can print `self`. This will print the name and class.